# URL Rewriting - A URL that satisfies it's own rule

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, umbraco

I'm trying to set up a url rewrite using the UrlRewriting.config file in Umbraco.

Am I correct in thinking that the URL Rewriting uses Perl-compatible regular expressions?

I need to redirect from `/events.aspx$` to `about-us/events.aspx$`, but obviously this causes an endless loop, resulting in a URL which looks like `about-us/about-us/about-us/about-us/events.aspx` etc.

Is there a way that I can stop the endless loop happening here? Apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere - it's a hard scenario to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `^/events.aspx$` (i.e. starts with /events.aspx) in the rewrite condition and then rewrite the URL to `about-us/events.aspx` so that the next time the request comes to the URL rewriter, the rewrite condition won't be satisfied. We used to do similar stuff with `mod-rewrite` in apache.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just anchor at the start as well?

`^/events\.aspx$` -> `about-us/events.aspx`